# Android: Suppress onClick when dragged or flicked

Tags: android

I have a view on which I want to add an onClickListener. Trouble is that the listener fires even when the user performs a drag operation. How do I suppress on click when the user drags, and only process when it is a click without dragging?

For completeness, am using something like below to add the onClickListener -

```
private void installClickHandler(final GraphicalView x) {
    x.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BillTablesActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can use onTouchListener to accomplish this

Comment: How about adding boolean flag `isDragging`? And when dragging starts set the flag to true value. And inside `onClick` method check if `isDragging` is false?

Comment: you might need to sleep for a short time to be sure that this flag is gets set in time

Answer (score 1):

set an [onTouchListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29), which either returns true if you dragging, or returns false otherwise allowing your [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to handle the event. in other words, it's up to you to decide whether to treat the touch even as a click, or not.

to decide if something is a click or a drag (or a long press), the implementation of your [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) will have to keep track of `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` events, and compare the time between the two. a short interval would be a click, a longer time period would be a drag or a long press.

the specific implementation is left as an exercise for the reader :)